# tear problem in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting, sculpt-mode

I don't know why this issue is happening.
there's a tear on the object's face
Can you help me solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Ok so the first thing that comes to my mind is normals. Try going to edit mode > a to select all > Shift+N to recalculate normals. Also, please provide more details if possible. Like what were the last actions you took before this happened. We might be able to narrow down the problem. This sometimes happens after remeshing.

Comment: If it's not the normals, it's hard to tell without the `.blend` file.
Please use [https://blend-exchange.com/](https://blend-exchange.com/)